# Extract all the <script> tags from an HTML file and store that in an NSArray- Objective C

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios

I am trying to get the src of all the script tags and i want to store that an in an array. I am really stuck with these any help would really be appreciated.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='static/tabthemes/js/json2.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='static/tabthemes/js/underscore.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='static/tabthemes/js/backbone.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='static/tabthemes/js/mustache.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='static/tabthemes/js/jquery.wipetouch.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/static/tabthemes/js/spin.js'></script>
```

Somebody please help me with this !! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `NSRegularExpression`, e.g.:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@" src='([^.]*)'" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

then check [`NSRegularExpression` reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for ways to match the actual data. In your case, the method

```
- (NSArray *)matchesInString:(NSString *)string options:(NSMatchingOptions)options range:(NSRange)range
```

should do exactly what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the dirty way : splitting the string at some markers you spotted (here I use the `src='` and then the last quote). It works with the string you gave, but it is not very safe. You should prefer the regex method given before.

Here is the piece of code you could try :

```
    NSMutableArray *retArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"src='"];
    for(int i = 1; i < components.count; i++)
    {
        NSArray *innerComponents = [[components objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"'"];
        [retArray addObject:[innerComponents objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
```

Comment: The dirty way did the trick . .Worked like charm !! I wish i could give u a vote up :) Thanks